# Why Windows doesn't recognize my smart card?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have valid GEMALTO smart card reader. I am using Windows 10,and when I try to change my PIN with Microsoft PIN tools, I got this
[image]

LET'S take a look at Device Manager
[image]

I looked at Device Settings
[image]
I change to unmetered
[image]

If it says that the device is working properly, what is wrong?
How to solve this problem?

Comment: That says the _reader_ is working. Does it recognize a card in it? Does it have the drivers for the card itself?

Comment: That error message suggests it needs an unmetered connection to download whatever additional drivers or utilities that are required.

Comment: @Mokubai Yes,all Gemalto drivers are installed,I changed connection to unmetered,stilll the same problem.

Comment: Did you click the "remove device" and unplug and replug it in after setting to unmetered?

Comment: @Mokubai Yes,I did.I t seems that it has to do with Microsoft security(I guess).

Comment: Have you installed the Gemalto drivers for your smartcard reader, rather than a generic smartcard driver?